# Trying to change the color of a dialog's button after closing it once

Tags: android-studio

so I created a dialog in android studio. I wanted the button to switch colors after it is clicked from red to blue and blue to red.

```
 if (btnsoundon.getText().toString().equals("ON"))
        {
            bluebtn=false;
            btnsoundon.startAnimation(scale1);
            btnsoundon.startAnimation(scale2);
            btnsoundon.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            mp.pause();
            btnsoundon.setText("OFF");


        }
        else if(btnsoundon.getText().toString().equals("OFF"))
        {
            bluebtn=true;
            mp.start();
            btnsoundon.startAnimation(scale1);
            btnsoundon.startAnimation(scale2);
            btnsoundon.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            btnsoundon.setText("ON");

        }
```

After they close the dialog I wanted to remember the color of the button. So I put this in the creating dialog function I created:

```
 if (bluebtn)
    {
        btnsoundon.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
    else if (!bluebtn)
    {
        btnsoundon.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

but for some reason when I reopen the dialog it starts with a blue button all the time. I cant figure out why. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's because the dialog is created each time you show it and the value of "bluebtn" is reset each time. You might get over this by saving the value to SharedPreferences

Comment: I declared bluebtn globaly. so bluebtn value should be saved. doesnt it?

Comment: above onCreate , can't get to paste it here as a code. sorry Im new to this website